# Set a integer limit in a entry widget in tkinter (python)

Tags: python, integer, tkinter, limit

How do I make it so that if person enters  a number higher than 3000, it prints out a custom message instead of calculating the factorial of that certain number?

I've tried 'if number > 3000, print "blah blah blah"', but it doesn't work. Think it has something to do with tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox, os

#calculates factorial of inputNumber
def calculate():
    number = inputNumber.get()
    inputNumber.delete(0, END)
    product = 1
    for i in range(int(number)):
        product = product * (i+1)
    facAnswer.delete(1.0, END)
    facAnswer.insert(END, product)

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Factorial Calculator")
cal.geometry('450x300+200+200')

#Enter the number you want the factorial of 
factorialNumber = IntVar()
inputNumber = Entry(cal, textvariable=factorialNumber)
inputNumber.pack()

#executes calculate function by pressing button
enterButton= Button(cal, text="CALCULATE!", width=20,command=calculate)
enterButton.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)

#Where the answer appears:
facAnswer = Text(cal)
facAnswer.insert(END, "Answer:")
facAnswer.pack()

cal.mainloop()
```

Comment: Define "print out". Where do you expect the message to appear?

Comment: in facAnswer, the Text widget

Comment: The `print` statement puts things on the standard output. How should it know that Text widgets exist, let alone that you want the text to appear in one, let alone which one?

Comment: Did you try calling `facAnswer.insert` with the error message to display, instead of the calculated result?

Comment: yes i did, it didn't do anything at all, just kept on calculatig the factorial

Comment: That seems hard to believe, considering that `facAnswer.insert` is how you put the calculated result there. Could you show the code you tried? P.S. the `factorial` function is actually provided directly in the standard library, in `math`.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to work for me. You could put everything in a class,
and try using `get()` on `factorialNumber`, to see if it makes a difference.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title("Factorial Calculator")
        self.geometry('450x300+200+200')

    # Enter the number you want the factorial of
        self.factorialNumber = tk.IntVar()
        self.inputNumber = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=
                                    self.factorialNumber)
        self.inputNumber.pack()

    # executes calculate function by pressing button
        enterButton= tk.Button(self, text="CALCULATE!",
                                width=20,command=self.calculate)
        enterButton.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)

    # Where the answer appears
        self.facAnswer = tk.Text(self)
        self.facAnswer.insert('end', "Answer:")
        self.facAnswer.pack()


    def calculate(self):
        number = self.factorialNumber.get()
        if number > 3000:
            print('The number is out of range.')
        else:
            self.inputNumber.delete(0, 'end')
            product = 1
            for i in range(int(number)):
                product = product * (i+1)
            self.facAnswer.delete(1.0, 'end')
            self.facAnswer.insert('end', product)


gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: @user1323395 I might have misunderstood what you were trying to do, I updated the method.

Comment: Hm... I try it and I get a Attribute Error. I'm pretty new to this so I have no idea what that means...

Comment: @user1323395 It sounds like you didn't put the self. prefix on something you're trying to manipulate in the calculate method.

Comment: hmmm i tried copying the exact code you sent me as well, and it still gives me one.

Comment: @user1323395 Ah the calculate method didn't get indented properly when I updated it. It will work now.